# Zebra Scanner 8178 onBarcode read event not getting fired

Tags: c#, events, barcode, barcode-scanner

DS8178 not firing the barcode read (scan ) event

I am trying to use the DS8178 scanner and capture the barcode read event, have registered the event, have followed the below sequence:

> 1. `cCoreScannerClass- cCoreScannerClass.Open()` - success
> 2. `cCoreScannerClass.ExecCommand()` , input xml with event details

passed, but after execution the param `outxml` is empty which should 
contain scanner details.

> 3. `OnBarcodeEvent` - which is not fired in code on scanner trigger of barcode.

Eventually when connected scanner is triggered to scan barcode, it does not get the onBarcodeEvent triggered it only picks up the textual barcode and prints on screen in the text field.

Any help is appreciated, we are trying first time configuration with the

scanner in C#.net code.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem, but I can't remember it well.

Please try setting your scanner to OPOS or SNAPI mode.
You can either set the mode using the [123Scan](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/scanning-systems/123scan.html) application or simply scan the barcode that is printed on the manual.

You can also check [this](https://youtu.be/rN5M6ATO708?list=PLrcZVTwQp0lesloWgP3gReIZZqst5Hb-z&t=118) as a reference.

Comment: any update? i m facing the same issue with ls2208

Comment: What do you mean? I solved the problem by putting the scanner into SNAPI mode.

Answer (score 0):

When the text is printed a textfield the scanner is probably in keyboard mode. This means that the scanner emulates a keyboard typing the barcode that is scanner. In the setup manual there are several barcodes that you need to scan to setup the scanner. Change the mode of the scanner from keyboard to USB